# I have an important message

Tags: cipher

I have an important message for everyone. Can you work out what it is?

- 29234652 $\rightarrow$ HELLO
- 54903217 $\rightarrow$ WORLD
- 1431168003 $\rightarrow$ ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you write down the numbers in

> base 36, where digits of 10 and above are represented using A-Z

then we get

> ```
> 29234652 = (17, 14, 21, 21, 24) = HELLO
> 54903217 = (32, 24, 27, 21, 13) = WORLD
> 1431168003 = (23, 24, 2, 32, 10, 27) = NO2WAR
> ```

So the important message is

> NO2WAR = **NO TO WAR**, which is a message against the [2021-2022 Russia-Ukraine Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021%E2%80%932022_Russo-Ukrainian_crisis).

Comment: Yep you got it!